# Magnetic Field Produced By Electromagnet Perpendicular Winding

Tags: emf, electromagnet

[image: Wire Direction]

If I wound wire like a cylinder (blue) and then continued in a perpendicular direction like a toroid (yellow), what would the magnetic field look like?

Comment: What would the field from each look like?

Comment: I'm curious if there is a combined state because it's the same wire being used, but going  in different directions.

Comment: Are you familiar with the superposition principle?

Comment: No, so I looked it up and I still don't quite understand. Would it have characteristics of one or both? Sorry, physics and the like are not things I really studied.

Comment: In short, both. What kind of an answer were you looking for? If you don't know about vectors, let alone how to visualize or manipulate them, I'm not sure what hope we have to describe how the field points in such an arrangement; other than perhaps preparing a 3D animation at significant effort, which would be a lot to ask from volunteers.

Comment: Other than it hopefully being an image or in more layman's terms, I wasn't expecting much. By no means am I asking people to go out of their way to make some elaborate animation. Also, I'm not sure why you think someone needs a deep understanding to get the gist of things. I'm uneducated on the subject, but I was able to get the basics from simple drawings I found online such as https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Elecmagnet.png. I was just unsure if the combo would be canceled out or create something strange.

Comment: That's the gist of it, but a plane cross-section works because it's axis-symmetric.  That's not the case here, and the field from one loop is coming "through the paper" of the plane of the other. Which is not so easy to draw or visualize. Let alone if you had wanted a quantitative measure (field strength and direction at points), which as an engineer, if I were asking this question, I would find more useful -- "the field is twisted from the solenoid case" isn't very useful to me -- so you can see there's a wide span of effort between easiest-case wave-of-the-hand and worst-case precision.

Comment: And given that range, I had no idea what level of precision you wanted; and again as an engineer, I wondered if it might be the worst case, so asked to clarify that.